# Unix fork() system call

Tags: c, unix, fork, system-calls

Good daytime to all

I am confused with `fork()`. Does fork() forks child process or only parent?

please help on some examples

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  if (fork()) {
    fork();
    printf(" X\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

is this how i suppose to build the processes:

```
    parent
      |
   /    \
Parent  Child
```

so the output would be

```
  X X X
```

another example is

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  fork();
  fork();
  fork();

  printf(" X \n");

  return 0;
}
```

the graph would be like this?

```
                 Fork start
                    /     \
                Parent    Child        1st fork done output 2 of X
                /  \      /   \
              P     C    P    C        2nd fork done output 4 of X
            / \    / \  /\    /\
           P  C   P  C P  C  P  C      3rd fork done output 8 of X
```

another question how can I draw

```
if (fork() || fork() || fork())
  fork();
```

or

```
if (fork() && fork())
  fork();
```

I would be glad if someone correct me.

Comment: I don't understand your drawings, and I don't understand your question. A successful `fork()` system call is better understood as a magical cloning of the process calling it.

Comment: the fork creates parent and child process, right?
like pid==0 for child and pid>0 for parent
so when i am forking()
and printing X and prints for child and parent

Comment: I suggest you to try each simple example by compiling it and adding statements like `printf("at line %d pid %d\n", __LINE__, (int)getpid()); fflush(NULL);` inside.

Comment: Voting to close as "not a real question": asking what happens in `if (fork() || fork() || fork()) fork();` is not going to help with "confusion".

Comment: Just want to understand is it possible to fork child process? or when fork executes it forks only parent process?

Comment: In reality you should always code something like `pid_t fpid = fork();` and test the result (i.e. `fpid`) immediately after  (you could even get `-1` with an error). You should not code `if (fork() && fork())` and even if the teacher asks it, you should decompose into simpler `mypid = fork();` assignments and tests.

Comment: @user1098207: I can't parse "fork parent process", obviously you can't fork() to create a process that already exists. The parent process is generally understood to be the process that first executes the `fork()` call. Then *two* processes return from the call, that's the magic of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fork` doesn't "create parent and child process", no. It creates a copy of the current process (the copy being the child and the current process being the parent). The distinction is done based on the `fork` return value.

Comment: fork();fork() is a copy of 2 processes, right? then fork();fork();fork() is a copy of 4 copied processes?

Comment: Read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28operating_system%29

Comment: Don't write or think of `fork(); fork();` but `pid_t pid1 = fork(); pid2 = fork();` and you have the nine cases for the positive, zero, negative values of `pid1` and of `pid2`